# Visual Studio - Disable Cursor positioning

Tags: visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio 2015 Text Editor automatically sets the Cursor Position in some situatiuons.

Here is what happens:

1. if -> tab -> tab
2. if (true)
   {

   }
3. I set the Cursor behind the close Bracket and press Enter.
4. Now my Cursor is inside the brackets, i wanted to have a new Line below the closing bracket!

How can i disable the behaviour?

Comment: I can't reproduce that, adds a new line just fine. Do you have R# or something similar installed that may modify that behaviour?

Comment: No, but some Addons like Productivity Power Tools..